# Ubuntu 12.04 - Add RAID 1 Array on existing device?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I read [How can I add a RAID 1 array in Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/230497/ubuntu-10-04-add-raid-1-array) and [Installing Raid 1 on Existing Ubuntu Server](http://ascend4.org/Installing_Raid_1_on_Existing_Ubuntu_Server).  However, I only have the following 2 hard drives:

`dev/sdb1` where Ubuntu 12.04 is currently running

`dev/sda1` empty disk

I want to create a RAID on these two hard drives, but I don't want to delete the `sdb1` partition because Ubuntu is working fine.

How can I create a RAID on existing device?

I performed

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sda1
```

Then

```
 mkfs -t ext2 /dev/md0
```

And I run

```
echo "DEVICE partitions" > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Then I change boot to `md0` in `grub2`

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(md0)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8fff7794-a156-46d2-92f8-4931d42abf36
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-root ro
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
```

But, when I want to add

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdb1
```

I always get

```
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a new RAID1 array with a "missing" device using the following in a terminal (may have to employ the `sudo` command):

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/sda1 missing
```

You'll be able to move all the data onto `/dev/md0`, boot with that, then add `/dev/hdb1` into the mirror:

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 -a /dev/hdb1
```

Backup your data first and get familiar with mdadm and software RAID on Linux to avoid shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Thx for answer. can you give me en example how to add hdb1 to mirror?

Comment: You'll need to read the mdadm and software RAID documentation to avoid losing your data and get familiar with it. For example, are your hard drives the same size? Probably not since one is IDE and one is SATA. You'll need to ensure the RAID device you create is not too large.

Comment: disks are the same size. hdb1 is sdb1, my mistake sorry. both disks are SATA1

Comment: i am reading mdadm but i am not sure how to mirror sdb1

Comment: I already edited how to add sdb1 to the mirror into the question.

Comment: Thx i see. but i get root@ubuntu-server:~# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot open /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy

Comment: i try stop it first and then restart but is the same.  mdadm --stop /dev/md0

Comment: You need to boot using /dev/md0 first.

Comment: you mean changing root (hd0,msdos1) in grub to root (md0)? but i still get Device or resource busy

Comment: i try everything even this howto http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-debian-squeeze but i don't know how to boot. now i get error when booting md0

Comment: Did you copy the data over to it?

Comment: yes sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk --force /dev/sda ke is in this howto: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-debian-squeeze

Comment: You made backups, right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are most of the way there.   I'm trying to do the same thing and found you on google.  Notwithstanding the issue that your drives may not be the same size (mine are), I think all you need to do is :

- boot Ubuntu live CD, add and start mdadm
- start your md0, partition it
- rsync -av from /dev/hdb1 to /dev/md0p1
- change grub to boot your raid
- reboot into your raid
- repartition your first disk
- add the other disk to the raid

Done

But that is only guessing :-)   It may be a week or so before I get to try it myself.

This is similar to something I've done - move an Ubuntu box from one piece of HW to another using rsync.  I learned there that you NEED to copy the OS from a live CD - you can't get a good copy of the OS when booted from the OS itself.

You want to

rsync -av --exclude-from=excludefile /source/ /destination/

and your exclude file looks like :

```
# Include
+ /dev/console
+ /dev/initctl
+ /dev/null
+ /dev/zero

# Exclude
- /dev/*
- /proc/*
- /sys/*
- /tmp/*
- lost+found/
- /media/backup/*
```