# RAID 1 mirroring

Tags: raid-1

i need to understand something. i have a dell poweredge server, when i was setting it up for the first time, i configured raid 1 on it and in the process of installing the OS, i partitioned the raid 1 drive into two. now i want to add another 2TB drive to raid 1, my question is, will the 2TB run as a separate drive or it will add up to the existing partitions. i hope am clear.

thank you. help.

Comment: partition 1st then mdadm

Answer (score 1):

Adding a drive to a RAID 1 should just mirror the data to the new drive, though it will depend on the quality of the RAID device you are using, and if it is hardware or software. It shouldn't matter if it's partitioned, the RAID should just copying whatever data is on the physical device.

Here's a similar question that may help add some details:
[Have two partitions in RAID1](https://superuser.com/questions/663883/have-two-partitions-in-raid1)