# Is it possible to enable RAID 1 without reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid

I would like to enable RAID 1 on my alrwady existing Ubuntu installation.

Is this possible without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: related: [How can I add a RAID 1 array in Ubuntu 10.04?](http://superuser.com/q/230497/172747)

Comment: Adding RAID arrays to an existing system is certainly possible. It gets interesting if you want to do that a system whose disk is already in use. In that case see http://superuser.com/questions/775691/having-trouble-setting-up-raid-1-on-fedora